# Which will be better for updating millions of records either trigger or batch class

Tags: trigger, batch, schedulebatch

I need to updated millions of records which is of currency type.So i need to write business logic for the same.So shall i go with trigger or Batch class.
In the case of a trigger, every time an invoice record is added, deleted or modified Amount will be recalculated.While in case of batch class,records will be updated based on a process that can be scheduled to run on a specific day and time of the month.

Comment: okay, so what is your question?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are doing.

If this is a onetime update: write a batch that fixes all of your records.

If this is a recurring thing: write a batch that fixes all of your records and then write a trigger to do that for every new record that will be created.

Comment: So i have to write both trigger and batch class to update smoothly.It is a recurring thing.I think only batch class will work fine.No need to write trigger on creation of records as batch will update that record also.

Comment: Yes. I'm assuming (because you didn't say) that you create a new field and this needs to get a value one way or another.  To do this the first time you can write your batch that queries all relevant records, makes the calculation, and updates the record.

To make sure that your data will keep up to date (new records being inserted) create a trigger that does the calculation on insert / update. Then you run the batch once, and in the future the trigger makes sure that the batch is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

We have recently released a new salesforce App called Rubrik which may help you with your updates. Rubrik is used to do mass update/creation/deletion of records based on user defined criteria. We know making mass changes can be scary, so there is the ability to preview the changes before fully committing them to the database. There is also a functionality to use Rubrik as a trigger, to process records as they are inserted/updated. This allows Administrators to do tasks that would usually require a developer.

In your case, you could use Rubrik to update your million of records one time and then set up Rubrik as a trigger to process any new records after.

You can learn more here: [Rubrik Features](http://rubrik.ucinnovation.com/features.html)

To try out Rubrik, please go to here: [Free Trial](http://rubrik.ucinnovation.com/freetrial.html)